# How do I grab a specific text from an element?

Tags: c#, selenium

```
<textarea>
   This URL will bring you to the desired page http://www.google.com 
</textarea>
```

In that block of HTML, i want to scrap the web page to get just the URL in thetextarea. How would I go about doing that?

I know how I can get all the text in the element, I just don't know how i only grab some of the text in the element.

Pointing me in the correct direction will also help greatly.

Comment: Maybe just get the text and do something like: text.Split(' ').First(x => x.Contains("www.")) ? Please don't resort to regex :)

Comment: It's hard to avoid not using Regex for this reason.  You could use string.Contains() but you'll have to account for the different URL patterns.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using regex, it's just that you don't really need it in this case. daniel's suggestion to split the string and then look for "http" is what I would have suggested.

Comment: @daniel You are correct. That worked best.

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with using regex if you don't care about readability and maintainability! :) Glad it worked @Travis !

Answer (score 1):

You can try using regex

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(http:)+\S+"); //regex expression
Match match = regex.Match("This URL will bring you to the desired page http://www.google.com");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
}
```

More details are present here http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex

Answer (score 0):

Code that @daniel posted in comment was correct

```
text.Split(' ').First(x => x.Contains("www."))
```